# Django I18n Translation of The whole document

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

when i start translating the django application.

```
{% trans 'Profilbild'%}
```

All other trans blocks **with umlaut** are not translated. What is the solution ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works, the `i18n` tag translates a string or variable, it only takes *one* argument. Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/)?

You probably want [blocktrans](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#std%3atemplatetag-blocktrans)

**UPDATE (the OP changed the question):**

1. Did you run `makemessages -l <desired_lang>` successfully
2. Did you run `compilemessages` successfully
3. Did you restart the Django process after these steps?

Comment: *"You probably want blocktrans"* Why? If you need only one word to be translated... And *"That's not how it works"*: according to the docs link you provide that is how it works.

Comment: @gertvdijk because he states only the _first_ argument to function 'trans' is translated...

Comment: I think he means that consecutive `{% trans ... %}` blocks aren't working (no translation).

Comment: IMO the question is just vague :)

Comment: The problem is other words without umlaut are translated. The trans with umlaut is a problem ... My Translation documents are encoded with utf-8 ... One example for a word that can't be translated correct is 'Über mich' ... After translating the whole html document there is 'Über mich' and i don't understand why.

Comment: all other trans values without umlaut are translated correct.